# KeyError when appending to a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to use a dictionary to record data relating to IP addresses, essentially an IP address can have a number of groups associated with it, and I need to capture info about the groups relating to that IP address (these are controller groups on a wireless system so the data is all relating to configuration of access points). I want something like:

```
{<ip_addr>: [{group_name: my_aps, total_aps: 22, total_active_aps: 12},
             {group_name: my-other_aps, total_aps: 15, total_active_aps:14},
             {...}
            ]
}
```

My script is looping through a list of groups (there are 300+) and pulling the info off the wireless controller. With each loop I obtain the details of the new group. But I can't work out how to then add the group dictionary to the list. I am trying (where group_details is the group dictionary and lms_ip is the address that I want to list it against):

```
lms_groups[lms_ip].append(group_details)
```

But I get:

```
KeyError: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

(IP address hidden fwiw)

The script seems to work up to that point, I think the dictionaries are being created ok.

Comment: use `defaultdict(list)` ?

Comment: Perhaps you should write a [MCVE] demonstrating the problem you're having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

*`dict.setdefault`*

```
lms_groups.setdefault(lms_ip, []).append(group_details)
```

---

**Option 2**

*`collections.defaultdict`*

```
from collections import defaultdict    
lms_groups = defaultdict(list)
...
lms_groups[lms_ip].append(group_details)
```

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks I completely missed how to accept the answer! Done

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this fix the error, but at least it's a better access to the dict.

```
ip_list = lms_groups.get(lms_ip, [])
ip_list.append(group_details)
lms_groups[lms_ip] = ip_list
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `dict.setdefault` rather than `get()` with a default and then unconditionally reassigning.